# Error reading CSV file using read_csv, but read.csv work?

Tags: r, csv, tidyr

I have the `arbuthnot.csv` file, store directly in the working direction.

I can not read it using `read_csv("arbuthnot.csv")`. However, read.csv() works. As I prefer to work with read_csv, how can I fix this problem?

```r
arbuthnot <- read.csv("arbuthnot.csv")
```

```r
arbuthnot <- readr::read_csv("arbuthnot.csv")
#> Error in `vec_as_location()`:
#> ! `...` must be empty.
#> x Problematic argument:
#> * call = call
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_Australia.1252      
#>  ctype    English_Australia.1252      
#>  tz       Australia/Sydney            
#>  date     2022-07-28                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  htmltools     0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#> 
#> [1] C:/Users/thanh/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/library
```

Comment: Are you able to post a portion of the CSV file (in a code block) that triggers the error? It sounds like its an unmet assumption in the `readr::read_csv` function, and it'll be much easier if we can actively debug an active error.

Comment: Hi R2evans, I fixed the problem by updating R. I think it is version conflict that lead to this error. I will post a portion of the CSV file later.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies on phone so can't test, try using the whole path to the file

eg

```
arbuthnot <- read_csv("C:\\documents\\folder\\arbuthnot.csv")
```

If that doesn't work try the same with col_types = NULL after the file path.

Cant quite remember the exact reason that makes a difference, its to do with how the file is read in (it bases the column type on the first n rows of the file).

Comment: I did copy the whole path, even try moving the files around, but it is not working. col_types = NULL not working, too.

I uninstalled then installed R, and the problem is gone now.